# Android add a submenu on my View's onclick, how?

Tags: android

Is there a way to show up a menu, when i click on any View?

thanks,

Leslie

Answer (score 4, accepted):

yes you can open menu on any click of view

just write  **openOptionsMenu();**  in setOnClickListener of your view

Comment: i just wanna show this on click: http://1.bp.blogspot.com/_zTrHGwhW4Tc/Sv_7TblS7cI/AAAAAAAAAWg/5hj4HNrTa_w/s320/09-11_v3.bmp how i can do that?

Comment: contextmenu is open on longClick not on Click and we can use ContextMenu most of for ListView.. in your case you can create Custum Dialog

Comment: I figure it out, so onClickListener i do this:     registerForContextMenu(linearLayoutChildrens);
   openContextMenu(linearLayoutChildrens);
 and my contextmenu appear

Comment: that goood then enjoy with android